# Store a sensitive password in SSIS Oracle connection string

Tags: ssis, passwords

Requirement -
I dont want my password to be shown to anyone in SSISDB.

My approach -

1. Created Oracle connection string Parameter.
2. Created a parameter which stores password.

   [image]
3. I have used connection manager expressions to append Password (variable) to connection string parameter.

   [image]
4. Deployed the solution to ssisdb.
5. Created a Password variable in DEV environment and made it sensitive so that no one can view it.

   [image]
6. Selected that password in project configuration so that at the time of execution of the ssis package, the password variable is used.

   [image]
7. created a SQL agent job to execute the package.
8. In configuration of SQL agent job, I have selected the DEV environment, but it is throwing an error because I have not made the password sensitive in SSIS Package but made it sensitive in DEV Environment variable.

   [image]

How to resolve it?

If I make it sensitive in package, then variable in not getting appended in connection string.

Comment: [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you mark something as Sensitive, then it has to be consistently treated as such. In your package, the parameter is not flagged a sensitive. Were it to be marked as such, then you'd have encountered this exception when you tried your string concatenation expression.

[image]

Were I you, I would undo the string concatenation you're using to build the connection string. Instead, you can directly feed the password to the password property of a connection manager. Switch to the Connection Managers tab and there you'll have your list of packages and then you directly modify the Password property

[image]